# Missing detail in graph traversal method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

So I've been scavenging the forums for a solution to this problem and I have this method for finding a node in a graph given a predicate:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> FindWhere<T>(this T root, Func<T, bool> predicate,
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> getChildren)
        where T : class
    {
        var stack = new Stack<T>();
        stack.Push(root);
        while (stack.Count != 0)
        {
            T item = stack.Pop();
            if (item != null)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
            foreach (var child in getChildren(item))
                stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
}
```

This should work most of the way, but how do I get the predicate into the method so that I can find any node in the graph that I wish to find? Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't this just be a modification of your if statement? if (item != null) should be if (item != null && predicate(item)) i think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda expression like this:

```
myClass.FindWhere(x => x.HasSomeProperty, y => y.GetChildren())
```

Or you can declare methods with the right signature and pass those in.

```
bool IsOkay(MyClass mc) { ... }
IEnumerable<MyClass> GetChildren(MyClass mc) { ... }
...
myClass.FindWhere(IsOkay, GetChildren)
```